# I am continuously getting this error on my VScode in Mac. I even tried resinstalling it and the extensions but its not working

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

[Running] cd "/Users/Rajesh/Desktop/a4/" && gcc q1.c -o q1 && "/Users/Rajesh/Desktop/a4/"q1
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_main", referenced from:
implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.071 seconds

Comment: Are you using an M1 Mac ?

Comment: I suggest you follow the suggestion and add -v. Do you have a main program? What libraries are you linking with?

Comment: Does q1.c contain a main() function?